# Object properties won't load in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableViewController that loads cells from a data source using AFNetworking.  The data loads async so I set a notif to update my tableView when new data is loaded. The reloadTable gets called every time new data arrives and updates my Object properties, but those properties won't load in my cellForRowAtIndexPath.

When I NSLog my properties in the reload table, they are correct. But the say null in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

Here is my code...

This creates a Object 'shifts' and starts loading the data, then receives a notif when new data is loaded and updates the table

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"game_id":self.gameID, @"player_id":_sharedPlayer.playerID, @"category_id":self.categoryID};

 _shifts = [[ClipShiftController alloc] init];
[_shifts fetchShifts:params];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(reloadTable:)
                                              name:@"clipLoaded"
                                            object:nil];
```

Here is my reloadTable:

```
- (void)reloadTable:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    Clip *clip = [self.shifts.shiftDataSet objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"clip counter %i",[self.shifts.shiftDataSet count]);
    NSLog(@"clip name %@",clip.name);
    i++;
}
```

here is cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Clip *clip = [_shifts.shiftDataSet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"CELL COUNTER %i",[_shifts.shiftDataSet count]);
    NSLog(@"CLIP CELL name %@",clip.name);
    NSLog(@"row called");

    cell.textLabel.text = @"hello";
    //This is null  cell.textLabel.text = clip.name;

    return cell;
}
```

Here is my Console Output

```
2013-08-26 12:16:50.831 One Six[15632:c07] clip counter 1
2013-08-26 12:16:50.831 One Six[15632:c07] clip name shift
2013-08-26 12:16:50.831 One Six[15632:c07] clip counter 2
2013-08-26 12:16:50.832 One Six[15632:c07] clip name shift
2013-08-26 12:16:50.832 One Six[15632:c07] clip counter 3
2013-08-26 12:16:50.832 One Six[15632:c07] clip name shift
2013-08-26 12:16:50.832 One Six[15632:c07] clip counter 4
2013-08-26 12:16:50.833 One Six[15632:c07] clip name shift
2013-08-26 12:16:50.833 One Six[15632:c07] clip counter 5
2013-08-26 12:16:50.833 One Six[15632:c07] clip name face off
2013-08-26 12:16:50.833 One Six[15632:c07] clip counter 6
2013-08-26 12:16:50.833 One Six[15632:c07] clip name face off
2013-08-26 12:16:50.834 One Six[15632:c07] clip counter 7
2013-08-26 12:16:50.834 One Six[15632:c07] clip name face off
2013-08-26 12:16:50.834 One Six[15632:c07] clip counter 8
2013-08-26 12:16:50.835 One Six[15632:c07] clip name shift
2013-08-26 12:16:50.835 One Six[15632:c07] CELL COUNTER 8
2013-08-26 12:16:50.835 One Six[15632:c07] CLIP CELL name (null)
2013-08-26 12:16:50.836 One Six[15632:c07] row called
2013-08-26 12:16:50.836 One Six[15632:c07] CELL COUNTER 8
2013-08-26 12:16:50.836 One Six[15632:c07] CLIP CELL name (null)
2013-08-26 12:16:50.837 One Six[15632:c07] row called
2013-08-26 12:16:50.838 One Six[15632:c07] CELL COUNTER 8
2013-08-26 12:16:50.838 One Six[15632:c07] CLIP CELL name (null)
2013-08-26 12:16:50.838 One Six[15632:c07] row called
2013-08-26 12:16:50.839 One Six[15632:c07] CELL COUNTER 8
2013-08-26 12:16:50.839 One Six[15632:c07] CLIP CELL name (null)
2013-08-26 12:16:50.839 One Six[15632:c07] row called
2013-08-26 12:16:50.840 One Six[15632:c07] CELL COUNTER 8
2013-08-26 12:16:50.840 One Six[15632:c07] CLIP CELL name (null)
2013-08-26 12:16:50.841 One Six[15632:c07] row called
2013-08-26 12:16:50.841 One Six[15632:c07] CELL COUNTER 8
2013-08-26 12:16:50.841 One Six[15632:c07] CLIP CELL name (null)
2013-08-26 12:16:50.842 One Six[15632:c07] row called
2013-08-26 12:16:50.842 One Six[15632:c07] CELL COUNTER 8
2013-08-26 12:16:50.844 One Six[15632:c07] CLIP CELL name (null)
2013-08-26 12:16:50.844 One Six[15632:c07] row called
2013-08-26 12:16:50.845 One Six[15632:c07] CELL COUNTER 8
2013-08-26 12:16:50.845 One Six[15632:c07] CLIP CELL name (null)
2013-08-26 12:16:50.846 One Six[15632:c07] row called
```

What is shows is 8 rows in my table view that say hello.

Comment: Why not show where/how you're storing the data?  It looks to me like that's the problem.

Comment: @NicholasHart Why would my data load and display in my reload data function but not cellForRowAtIndexPath:? I'll update my question with my data

Comment: Ok, I didn't quite catch how you were storing the data.  Can you show the declaration for `Clip`?  It looks like it's losing its data.  Perhaps your properties are weak, not strong.

Comment: @NicholasHart BOOM! you nailed it Thank you.. Why did I put weak properties... ?? dumb.  Make and answer and I'll except it. thanks

Comment: if you ask about properties why dont you show us the property declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that in your model objects you declare your properties using strong, not weak.  Without seeing your code I guessed that was the most likely issue.  There are some cases where you do want to use weak (eg: IBOutlets in your view controllers), but not in a case where you have a data object that owns its data.

Answer (score -1):

You never alloc and init the var 'cell', check your code, the var 'cell' is still nul.

Comment: He is using iOS 6's [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW92), not `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. If the storyboard is set up correctly and the cell class is registered he must not deal will cell creation.

Comment: (and btw: read the comments below the question — this problem is solved.)

Answer (score -2):

I think because you mix ivar (_shifts) and the property (self.shifts). If you use an older version of Xcode you must @synthesize the property in the implementaion part with this code :

```
@synthesize shifts = _shifts;
```

If you use the last versions of Xcode it is not necessary to declare ivar _shifts variable juste declare the property with this code :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)  <YourObjectClass>* shifts;
```

It's necessary in all location on your code you used self.shifts property and not the ivar variable _shifts

Comment: *"It's necessary in all location on your code you used self.shifts property and not the ivar variable _shifts"*. This is not necessary.

Comment: Why does he have to use the property?

Comment: if you use ivar without retain you can have somes crashes, with the property the mechanism retain release is sure. Apple recommended to use ivar only in assessor override, but is not prohibited to use it

Comment: wrong. this would be true in MRC and only for assigning objetcs to the property.

Comment: explain me what is MRC ?

Comment: if you have ever heard of ARC: it stands for Automatic Reference Counting. Now try to guess, what MRC stand for.

Comment: Ok my sample is in MRC of course and in this case is right. You are harsh

Comment: what makes you believe, that OP is using MRC? and still your statement that properties must be use is wrong.

Comment: for example: lets say OP is using an mutable array. it the array is created and retained, there is no need to use the property to add an new object.